# Firebase + Mlab: How to secure both?

Tags: firebase, security, ionic-framework, heroku, mlab

Hello fellow developers,

I have an app using Firebase realtime as a main database (users info, authentication, chatting), and also using Mlab as a second database for situations that require more complex queries.

I make GET/POST queries to my heroku hosted node server, which then connects to my mlab (through mongoose).

But my question is the following:

How can I secure this secondary database / heroku endpoint?

How can I make sure someone will not spam my heroku endpoint with request?

One way would be through JWT tokens if I understand correctly, but that would require another authentification, on top of my firebase one?

Is there any other way to make sure only someone from my app (developed with Ionic) can send requests to my heroku; and to make sure one single users cannot create "loops" to send thousands of request in a second to my server?

Any feedback would be greatly appreciated, I am really clueless for now.